# What is the architecture needed for node.js web app?

Tags: ajax, node.js, web-applications

I am just looking to be pointed in the right direction on what resources I need to brush up on to create a node.js web app. I have seen some great tutorials but when nothing that touches on what I need.

I have read smashing js but it is just about the syntax.

So my server side is node but what about the form design? What is the easiest framework for a beginner to get started on a web?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The site [node frameworks](http://nodeframework.com/) will give you a list of available frameworks.
I'm quite new to NodeJS but what I discovered the hard way is that in the nodeJS ecosystem, the most popular libraries are based on Express and/or Connect (Express being itself build on top of Connect).

So if you choose another framework, you could be stuck like I was, when trying to integrate some popular libraries like Passport for authentication. 
Moreover Express popularity will allow you to find many tutorials.
That's why I would recommend you to use it.

update: you may discover popular modules for node on [NodeJS Modules](https://nodejsmodules.org/)

Comment: I was reading about a framework called super hero. It looked pretty cool but limited support. So with node connect and express that is all that I need to get started?

Comment: Just Express. It will include Connect.

Comment: If it is okay to follow up while we have this open thread, what role does jade play in development?

Comment: Jade is a template engine for your views. It will insert the variables in the HTML you designed.

Comment: This is a great tut. http://cwbuecheler.com/web/tutorials/2013/node-express-mongo/

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to steer clear of frameworks and use smaller modules for building up your stack.

https://github.com/Raynos/http-framework

Is a great resource w/ lots of links to modules and examples for different web app cases.

Comment: Derek because I am new to node, I think including a framework will help in the learning process.